Why does my Kotlin program fail to compile?
I'm currently learning Kotlin and using https://play.kotlinlang.org/ to compile my code.
I tried to create a very simple program, collecting user input and giving output.
Howevery, it doesn't run.
fun main() {
   println("Give me a number of minutes!") 
   var input:String = readLine()!!
   var inputInMinutes = input.toInt()
   var resultInSeconds:Int = 0
   resultInSeconds = (inputInMinutes*60)
   println("That is " + resultInSeconds + " seconds!") 
}

I was expecting the program to compile and run, but it displays the following error message:
Give me a number of minutes!
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at FileKt.main (File.kt:7) 
 at FileKt.main (File.kt:-1) 
 at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (:-2) 

Is there a mistake in my code or does the online IDE not allow for user input?

An exception is happening at runtime, not compile time (i.e. the program does not fail to compile).

It looks like the input string is empty due to readLine() not working property on this online emulator. See this for more info.

right, I think it works in other online tools like https://www.jdoodle.com/compile-kotlin-online, so it seems to be indeed tool-related. Can you recommend a tool that supports console input and is maybe faster that jdoodle?

I posted a complete answer with a possible solution.

When you post a stack trace showing line numbers, it would help to point out which line in your code it is. In this case, File.kt:7 refers to line 3 of your listing, containing    var input:String = readLine()!!.

By the way, in case you're following an old course, there is a newer method called readln() which doesn't need the !! after it, and gives you a better error message when something goes wrong.

@wohlstad that's your first answer on a kotlin question. amazing, how quickly you can pick up a language and give correct explanations!

@ChristophRackwitz thanks, I got to the question via the Staging Ground, and did some googling and played around with the Kotlin Playground. I guess some general experience with other languages doesn't hurt ;-)

@KlitosKyriacou I think you posted more comments here (on answers below) than I can see now. can you confirm?

@ChristophRackwitz there was a comment with a correction under my answer below, which I flagged as "no longer needed" after I editted and fixed (as you can see in the edit history). The flag was accepted and the comment deleted. Do you think this is inappropriate ?

@wohlstad I suspected that you had it removed.

@ChristophRackwitz isn't that what's "no longer needed" flag is for ?

I mean, you could name him as a co-author, since he provided the correct explanation after your incorrect explanation of something in a language you're not an expert in, which taught you what's really going on, and which you accepted and incorporated. I believe hiding that should be below your standards.

@ChristophRackwitz I honestly believed at the time that the main point of the issue was already given in my original answer, and that the correction was not major. But anyway after reading your last comment I wanted to make sure credic is given when dued and so editted now to clarify.


Why does my Kotlin program fail to compile?

Actually it does compile without errors.
An exception like you observed is thrown at runtime, not compile time.
Regarding your specific exception:
According to this post in the site's forum,  the Kotlin Playground does not suppport interactive input (like you attempted with readLine()).
Therefore readLine() returns null, and as @KlitosKyriacou rightly pointed out to me readLine()!! which performs a null-assertion then throws the exception you see (originally I mistakenly assumed the exception was thrown by input.toInt()).
A possible solution (as suggested in the post mentioned above) is to write your own function that emulates readLine():
val input = mutableListOf("123") // here you should put your input
fun myReadLine(): String? {
    val line = input.firstOrNull()
    input.removeAt(0)
    return line
}

fun main() {
   println("Give me a number of minutes!") 
   var input:String = myReadLine()!!
   var inputInMinutes = input.toInt()
   var resultInSeconds:Int = 0
   resultInSeconds = (inputInMinutes*60)
   println("That is " + resultInSeconds + " seconds!") 
}

Output:
Give me a number of minutes!
That is 7380 seconds!

Live demo

The NullPointerException exists in this specific case because there is no input, therefore the not null operator "!!" should not be used. It is probably unnecessary to use an additional function, the most optimal way here is to handle the nulls carefully between each of the operations. A second problem exists that the input may not be a valid integer, therefore toIntOrNull should be used. Also it is better to use string interpolation in Kotlin, as it is more readable.
fun main() {
    println("Give me a number of minutes!")
    val input:String? = readlnOrNull()
    val inputInMinutes = input?.toIntOrNull()
    val resultInSeconds = inputInMinutes?.let { it * 60 }
    if (resultInSeconds == null){
        println("Invalid input: $input")
    }
    else {
        println("That is $resultInSeconds seconds!")
    }
}

